# Wiki software that has page access control

Tags: linux, wiki, user-management

Is there any wiki software that allows me to control who can view or edit page *X* per user or users group?

For example, don't allow user1 and user2 (or group A?) from reading page *X*.

It is better if it runs on CentOS Linux.

Comment: I think this is a standard feature of most wikis, like MediaWiki and PmWiki.

Comment: No. MediaWiki does not support. I think that I read it somewhere in there documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[**DokuWiki**](https://www.dokuwiki.org/) supports [access control lists (ACL)](https://www.dokuwiki.org/acl).

DokuWiki is a free/libre wiki software, using PHP and flat files (no database). It [seems to be](https://pkgs.org/download/DokuWiki) available from CentOS repositories. The DokuWiki wiki also has some notes about the [configuration under CentOS](https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:centos).

Rules can be set

- per page (e.g., `recipes:rice-soup`) and per page namespace (e.g. `recipes:*`), and
- per user (e.g., `alice`) and per user group (e.g., `@family`).

The following permissions are available:

- `none`
- `read`
- `edit`
- `create` (only for namespaces)
- `upload` (only for namespaces)
- `delete` (only for namespaces)

You manage the ACL from a central page in the admin section, where you can also see a table of all permissions set by you:

> [image: Screenshot of DokuWiki’s ACL plugin]

<sub>(Screenshot from the [ACL plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:acl) page, which describes the numbered sections.)</sub>